# A and CNAME records vanish overnight on AD Integrated DNS zone

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

I have a Windows Server 2008 AD Integrated DNS zone across two domain controllers, I have added various CNAMEs pointing to our Build and Dev Web servers to support or continuous integration process.

These CNAME, and the A record for a server vanish over night, not all of them just a small selection usually between 5 and 7 days after they were created.

- No one else in the company has touched the config (only 2 of us have access, I have primary responsibility for managing DNS).
- DNS Scavenging is disabled on both DNS servers.
- There are no error messages or warnings in the Event Logs.

Any ideas, suggestions or solutions appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a replication issue. Do you have any issues when forcing replication?

Comment: DNS scavenging has no effect on manually created DNS records unless you manually set the "Delete this record when it becomes stale" check box when you create the record.

Comment: @Nixphoe no issue with replication, automatic or manual. The changes appear on both DNS servers promptly and vanish simultaneously overnight.

Comment: @joeqwerty good to know, however I don't have that check box only TextBox for Name, Text Box for FQDN and a Check Box for "Allow any authenticated user to update all DNS..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd still suspect scavenging, personally; those settings have a habit of not working right.  The per-zone settings and per-server settings combine to make for some strange behavior.

But, we don't have to guess at what's going on.  Turn on the `Directory Service Changes` security audit category on your domain controllers; more info on how to do this [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731607%28WS.10%29.aspx).

You will then get events in your security log (specifically, `5136` for changes or `5141` for deletions) that communicate exactly who, what, and when the entries were messed with.

Comment: Thanks, I have enabled auditing - we shall see what shows up.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a duplicate DNS zone.

Use the following resources to check:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverDS/thread/afb2c23b-5c2c-4ce1-9e94-07fa929dddcb
http://msmvps.com/blogs/acefekay/archive/2009/09/02/using-adsi-edit-to-resolve-conflicting-or-duplicate-ad-integrated-dns-zones.aspx