# Member Server DNS records being removed over night

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Following further investigations from my [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/259564/a-and-cname-records-vanish-overnight-on-ad-integrated-dns-zone), and the good advice of @Shane Madden I have the following environment:

- 2x Windows Server 2008 R2 Member Servers

  - COSTELLO (Build Server)
  - GRECO (SQL Server)
- 2x Windows Server 2008 Domain Controllers

  - RONNIE
  - REGGIE
- 16 Client Machines, Mix of:

  - Windows 7
  - OSX

Occasionally the DNS records for the two Member Servers are removed.

I have tried the following:

- Disabled Ageing and Scavanging at both the **server** and the **zone** level.
- Disabled then re-enabled the 'Register this connection's address in DNS' for each server.
- [Enabled `Directory Service Changes` security auditing](https://serverfault.com/questions/259564/a-and-cname-records-vanish-overnight-on-ad-integrated-dns-zone/259683#259683).

I have gone through the `System`, `Security` and `DNS Server` event logs on both Domain Controllers and the Member Servers and can not find anything related to DNS records being removed or modified. I have checked replication is working correctly by manually creating records on one server and watching them replicate to the other.

There does not appear to be any rhyme or reason as to why these records are deleted it happened 5 days ago, then during the day yesterday and again overnight.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have one or two DNS servers? I am also wondering if they are set as a primary and secondary rather than reading from Active Directory and the registry (AD integrated zones).

I would also try this command and look at the results: dcdiag /test:dns /dnsrecordregistration

I realize that 2008 does not have WINS, but are you running WINS anywhere? Check your DHCP settings to make sure they are not giving out WINS and your statics to make sure there is nothing there either. There have been known conflicts in the past all the way back to Windows 2000: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/171998

Is there possibly a stray DHCP server out there? The command "netsh dhcp list" could help find out.

Comment: For some reason I hadn't even seen this answer, I shall have a look in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your DNS scavenging settings? This can cause unexpected disappearances of DNS entries.

Comment: Yes, both on the server level and the zone level.

Comment: You may not have noticed where the OP stated "Disabled Ageing and Scavanging at both the server and the zone level."